# Wave equation written as a system of first order PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Consider the wave equation

$${\partial^2 u\over \partial x^2}={\partial^2 u\over \partial t^2}$$

for a smooth function $u(x,t)$.

i. Letting $v={\partial u / \partial x}$ and $w={\partial u / \partial t}$, write down a system of four first-order partial differential equations for $u,v$ and $w$ which is equivalent to the wave equation.

My solution is

$${\partial v \over \partial x}={\partial^2 u\over \partial x^2}={\partial^2 u\over \partial t^2}={\partial w \over \partial t}$$

$${\partial v \over \partial t}={\partial \over \partial t}{\partial u\over \partial x}={\partial \over \partial x}{\partial u\over \partial t}={\partial w \over \partial x}$$

Is this the whole solution? The question says there are four equations in the system.

ii. Let
$$G(x,t)=g''(x-a(t)) ,$$
where $g$ and $a$ are smooth. Combine the four equations from the previous part i. with the following two equations,

$${\partial v \over \partial x}+{\partial w \over \partial t}=2G(x,t)\,,\quad{\partial v \over \partial t}+{\partial w \over \partial x}=-2\dot a(t)G(x,t)\,,$$

to obtain a first-order system of the form

$${\partial u \over \partial x}=f_1^1(x,t,u,v,w) \quad {\partial u \over \partial t}=f_2^1(x,t,u,v,w)$$
$${\partial v \over \partial x}=f_1^2(x,t,u,v,w) \quad {\partial v \over \partial t}=f_2^2(x,t,u,v,w)$$
$${\partial w \over \partial x}=f_1^3(x,t,u,v,w) \quad {\partial w \over \partial t}=f_2^3(x,t,u,v,w)$$

where $f_i^\alpha(x,t,u,v,w)$ are functions that you should find explicitly.

My solution is

$${\partial v \over \partial x}={\partial w \over \partial t}\,,\quad{\partial v \over \partial t}={\partial w \over \partial x}\,,\quad{\partial v \over \partial x}+{\partial w \over \partial t}=2G(x,t)\,,\quad{\partial v \over \partial t}+{\partial w \over \partial x}=-2\dot a(t)G(x,t)\,,$$

$${\partial v \over \partial x}={\partial w \over \partial t}=G(x,t)\,,\quad{\partial v \over \partial t}={\partial w \over \partial x}=-\dot a(t)G(x,t)\,,$$

Then the system can be written as
$${\partial u \over \partial x}=v \quad {\partial u \over \partial t}=w$$
$${\partial v \over \partial x}=G(x,t) \quad {\partial v \over \partial t}=-\dot a(t)G(x,t)$$
$${\partial w \over \partial x}=-\dot a(t)G(x,t) \quad {\partial w \over \partial t}=G(x,t)$$

Is this correct? Or is there more to it that this.

iii. Using the Frobenius theorem, show that the preceding system has a solution if $\dot a^2(t)=1$ (you don’t need to write down the solution explicitly).

I'm not sure how to approach this part.